# Internet Explorer only - OpenIdConnectProtocolExcep‌​tion: invalid_request

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET MVC template generated site with Azure AD authentication. It seems to work fine for everyone but one user, when using IE, instead of getting redirected to Azure for login, gets the following exception:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectProtocolExcep‌​tion: invalid_request
```

The user tried it with Chrome and was redirected and logged in fine.

I of course, cannot reproduce it, and it's not a kind of user I can call upon to go through all the necessary troubleshooting.

So, my questions are:

1. Any ideas what this means? Microsoft's docs simply say "Protocol error, such as a missing required parameter."
2. If I were to catch this error, what should I do on the server side? I was thinking about redirecting the user to `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut` maybe? Or should I just display a page with "Clear your cookies in IE and try again?"

Relevant setup code:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
    string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                   AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
                   {
                       var code = context.Code;
                       ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                       string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                       AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                       AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                       code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   },
                    AuthenticationFailed = notification =>
                    {
                        var exception = notification.Exception;
                        if (exception is OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException
                            && (exception.Message.Contains("IDX10316") || exception.Message.Contains("IDX10311")))
                        {
                            notification.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                        else if (string.Equals(notification.ProtocolMessage.Error, "access_denied", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        {
                            notification.HandleResponse();
                            notification.Response.Redirect("/Account/NoAzureADAccess");
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code where you are doing the redirect and how you have configured the authentication?

Comment: I posed the config code. I added a few things to the boiler plate code that came from VS template: 1. redirect uri for testing from developer machine vs. staging site, vs. production site. 2. Authenticated code exceptions: first one to handle an error I was having when user would log in, then hit back and get a noonce exception. Second when user would arrive at the page, but without appropriate Azure AD permissions. We would send them to a custom access denied error page.

Comment: @Ilya - can you add a few correlation ids and time frames where you see the problem?

Comment: @Ilya - usually when authentication works for one user using a browser but fails with IE or Edge, two issues may be in play: 1. Security Zones: need to check how user's security zones are configured and if requests are crossing security zones. Please check this. Another possibility is that the URL formed may be way too large for this specific user and the browser won't support a large URL. For this case, a Fiddler trace may help.

Comment: @AndreTeixeira Thank you for your replies. I'm still investigating an ability to reproduce the problem so I can get more information. I'll definitely check URL lengths next time...